# Tracking templete to google ads account

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I want to add a tracking template on the account level via google ads API, but I am not able to found proper documentation to do it, Is anyone have idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a mutateCustomerRequest to the customer service. https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/CustomerService#mutatecustomer

Field masks are:

`customer.tracking_url_template = "{lpurl}?device={device}" customer.final_url_suffix = ( "keyword={keyword}&matchtype={matchtype}" "&adgroupid={adgroupid}" )`